# Looping a new <q-item> with <q-popoup-edit> nested doesn't work in quasar framework

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework

I have been searching for solution for my problem, but still not resolved :')..

Anyway, Thanks so much for the help, Masters :)

So,

I have a button for add new task with this code inside the  q-item-section  , but when I clicked it, it is not adding new item as a expected..

```
<q-btn
                  @click="addMore"
                  class="text-weight-bolder"
                  label="Add"
                  size="14px"
                  color="white"
                  flat
                  icon-right="mdi-plus-circle-outline"
                />
```

By clicking above button, it will shows a new item (by using following code below), which is needed to be filled by users

```
<q-item v-for="task in todoOthers2" :key="task">
              <q-item-section avatar>
                <div class="cursor-pointer size-16px">
                  {{ task.time }}
                <q-popup-edit v-model="time" class="bg-grey-2 text-white" :cover="false" :offset="[0, 10]" v-slot="scope">
                  <q-input filled v-model="todoOthers2.time" mask="time" :rules="['time']">
                  <template v-slot:append>
                    <q-icon name="access_time" class="cursor-pointer text-primary">
                      <q-popup-proxy transition-show="scale" transition-hide="scale">
                        <q-time v-model="time">
                          <div class="row items-center justify-end">
                            <q-btn v-close-popup label="Close" color="primary" flat />
                          </div>
                        </q-time>
                      </q-popup-proxy>
                    </q-icon>
                  </template>
                  </q-input>
                </q-popup-edit>
                </div>
              </q-item-section>
              <q-item-section no-wrap >
                <div class="cursor-pointer text-weight-bolder" style="width: 100px">
                {{task.activity}}
                <q-popup-edit v-model="todoOthers2.activity" class="bg-grey-2 text-white" :cover="false" :offset="[0, 10]" v-slot="scope">
                  <q-input  v-model="scope.value" dense autofocus counter @keyup.enter="scope.set">
                    <template v-slot:append>
                      <q-icon name="edit" />
                    </template>
                  </q-input>
                </q-popup-edit>
              </div>
              </q-item-section>
              <q-item-section top side>
                <div class="text-grey-8 q-gutter-xs">
                  <q-btn size="12px" color="secondary" flat dense round icon="mdi-check-circle" />
                  <q-btn size="12px" color="negative" flat dense round icon="mdi-delete" />
                </div>
              </q-item-section>
            </q-item>
```

Here is the setup()

```
setup() {
const todoOthers2 = ref({
      activity:"Add Your Task Here",
      time:"08:00"

function addMore(){
      todoOthers2.value.push({
        activity: "Add Your Task Here",
        time:"08:00"
      })

return {
      todoOthers2,
      addMore,
    }
}
```